# System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "csfml-audio-2": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sfml

System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "csfml-audio-2": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

```
Music mus1 = new Music("path\to\mp3\file.mp3");
```

Не смотря на то что у меня есть csfml-audio-2.dll

[image: <code>Файлы</code>]

Comment: Зависимость может быть вложенной. Т.е. на загрузке указанного модуля не загрузилось что-то другое.

Comment: Как это можно проверить?

Comment: Открыв исполняемый файл программы в [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) — это просмотрщик импортов и экспортов.

Comment: Я установил OpenAL, и теперь у меня эта ошибка пропала, но теперь у меня SFML.LoadingFailedException: "Failed to load music from file path\to\mp3\file.mp3" Возможно mp3 не поддерживается?

Comment: Товарищ, а вы какие цели преследуете? Прослушиваете/редактирование/запись аудио-файлов?

Comment: Цель - Прослушивание

Comment: Проблема решена, всем спасибо.

Comment: кто нибудь напишите ответ с Dependency Walker чтоб я его лучшим отметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил OpenAL и заработало. Спасибо людям в комментариях, которые предлагали Dependency Walker